# Friend template function

Tags: c++, templates, friend

If I have

```
namespace A
{
        template<class T>
        inline void SomeFunc(T& archive, Object* object)
        {
            // ...
        }
}
```

and a non-template class

```
namespace B
{
    class Manager
    {
        // ...
        template <typename T, typename U> friend void A::SomeFunc(T& t, U* u);
    };
}
```

why doesn't class `Manager` recognize `A::SomeFunc()` as a friend?

**What I'm trying to do:** I'm gonna have a good number of these `SomeFunc`s, all taking different `U` classes (which derive from the same base), so I was looking for a clean way to do it without befriending tons of these functions.

Comment: Because they're not the same function? Note the different number of template arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of template arguments matter. You are befriending a template that takes *two* template arguments, but the real template has only one. They are different entities.

Your friend declaration should be:

```
template<class T>
friend void SomeFunc(T&, Object*);
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thing is I'm gonna have a good number of these `SomeFunc`s, all taking different `U` classes (which derive from the same base), so I was looking for a clean way to do it. Until now, I don't have a solution.

Comment: @KristianD'Amato: The need for friendship is rare. Needing to befriend many different functions is even rarer. Maybe you could take a look at your design and refactor it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I protected the constructors to control object creation, but I guess that's gonna remain a fantasy.